# Can't delete a row from Mysql Not metadata-lock

Tags: mysql, locking, metadata

I am a new-baby in MySQL, so I follow the instructions but there is something wrong! **I can delete a whole table except the first row**.

Here is the code about **create table** that I copy from others

```
CREATE TABLE `top_100` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ranking` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`stars` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`release_time` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`score` FLOAT(3,1) NOT NULL,
`img_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE INDEX `title` (`title`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=337;
```

Now I drop several rows successfully, but the first-row I try everything, but it doesn't work.
here is the row

id ranking title stars release_time score img_url

1     1              '霸王别姬'                0.0

I search several methods like **drop table or DELETE FROM top_100 WHERE id=1**
, but this instruction doesn't work.  The HeidiSQL is stuck!

Someone says you may fall into **the metadata lock** but I kill the process id
, it doesn't work.

I am confused, having no idea.